# Connection between the Fourier transform of f and |f|

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

If $f\in L^p(R)$ with $1\leq p\leq 2$, then Hausdorff-Young inequality implies that the Fourier transform $\widehat{f}\in L^{p'}$, $p'$ is the dual exponent of $p$, and
$$
\|\widehat{f}\|_{L^{p'}}\lesssim \|f\|_{L^p}.
$$
We note that $f\in L^p$ is equivalent to $|f|\in L^p$, so we find $\widehat{|f|}\in L^{p'}$ and
$$
\|\widehat{|f|}\|_{L^{p'}}\lesssim \|f\|_{L^p}.
$$
So my question arises, does there exist connection between $\|\widehat{f}\|_{L^{p'}}$ and  $\|\widehat{|f|}\|_{L^{p'}}$ ? Precisely, does the following
$$
\|\widehat{f}\|_{L^{p'}}\lesssim \|\widehat{|f|}\|_{L^{p'}}
$$
holds? Note that $p=2$ it is a trivial by Plancherel theorem.

Comment: Have you tried looking in Katznelson's book, in the remarks and examples surrounding his discussion of the Hausdorff-Young inequality?

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't find the answer there.

Comment: Have you tried writing $|f(x)|=s(x)f(x)$ (where $s:\mathbb R\to\{-1,1\}$ is the sign of $f$) and studying the convolution that arises from the Fourier transform of $|f|$? I'm not sure if it takes you anywhere, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The inequality $||\hat{f}||_{L^p} \lesssim || \hat{|f|} ||_{L^{p}}$ does not hold for $p \neq 2$. This is, perhaps, easier to see in the case of Fourier series on the circle. A sketch of a contstruction is given in my answer to another mathoverflow quesion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143342/lp-norm-of-fourier-series-in-terms-of-coefficients-p-neq-2/143393#143393). This example can be modified to work in Euclidean space as well.